# Shopify - Fetching Multiple Shops from API

Tags: api, shopify

In Shopify API, suppose I have multiple shops under one account and I want to display all my shops in my application. So, is there any way by which I can get all my shops from one API?

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial. Each shop is stored in a Shops table, where you store the unique myshopify_domain name, and the oAuth token you received when the App was installed in the shop. Next you use SQL to do a SELECT * FROM Shops and voila, all your shops are available to you to process as you wish.